# Exception handling to ensure all-or-nothing execution

Tags: java, jdbc, exception, transactions, atomic

I'm creating a Java application that must both write to a database and talk to another application. Both of these tasks should occur in an all or nothing manner.

```
try{
  //.. execute JDBC query
  //.. talk to other application
  //.. commit JDBC query
} catch (Exception e){
  //.. rollback JDBC query
} finally {
  //.. close JDBC objects
}
```

In this case, is it acceptable practice to catch Exception rather than a subclass of Exception, and rollback?

Comment: Yes, you want to catch anything that can go wrong in either the JDBC query or the communication with the other application.

Comment: Yes.. See, you are doing a Rollback independent of the exception caught... So, instead of having several different catch statements to do "the  same thing" (you are not handling different exceptions differently) , catch Exception to handle everything in the same way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to act differently on different exceptions (which does not seem to be the case), what you are doing is correct since you want to do the same actions regardless of the exception.

As a minor note though, please do make sure that you log exceptions. Since you are dealing with an application, sending it some kind of notification that there was an error can also help who ever is using that application.

Comment: @Yes, most of the times,a simple log message can save you from hours of digging through code.